# TextBox behaves differently when losing focus in different ways

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-runtime

The WinRT TextBox control has a delete button that shows up when the control has focus and there is text in it.

When the control loses focus by tapping outside of it or tabbing outside of it, the delete button disappears.

When the control loses focus by tapping in a different app (two apps are up in splitscreen), the delete button doesn't disappear.

Is there a way to detect the different lost focus events? Nothing from the sender or RoutedEventArgs is different in the two cases where the control loses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle `Window.Activated` to check if the whole app has lost focus:

> This event occurs when a Window has been activated or deactivated by
>   the system. An app can determine what the status of the Window
>   activation is by checking the
>   WindowActivatedEventArgs.WindowActivationState property. A Window
>   could be visible on screen but not be active (for example, in snapped
>   apps). Additionally, if any other parts of the system takes focus away
>   from the window, this event will occur. This could happen as a result
>   of user interaction or code, and the WindowActivationState will
>   indicate which action has taken place.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.activated.aspx